# Lambda :published version from console with snapstart enabled giving function initilization error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

While enabling the snapstart for existing lambda function giving below error

> couldn't create version X of function funName. An error occurred
> during function initialization

No error logs in the cloud watch.
Steps performed:

1. set snap start to **On** from general configuration.
2. lambda version-> publish new version -> error : couldn't create version X of function, error occurred during initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that some of your initialization code (a static initializer or constructor) is throwing an exception. I don't think that there is any way to directly view the error that SnapStart encountered, but you can easily replicate it by running your code using your lambda's `$LATEST` version.

SnapStart cannot be enabled on `$LATEST`, so a cold start on `$LATEST` will execute all of the same initialization code that SnapStart would before it takes the snapshot.

Before you even do that, the best thing to do is to write some junit tests for your lambda and run them locally and see if any exceptions occur.

Otherwise:

1. Go to your lambda function in the AWS console.
2. If you did not do so already, upload your jar. Do not create a new version yet.
3. In the console, run a test for your lambda. Make sure you are using the `$LATEST` version, not a published numeric version. This will cause the initialization code to be run during the cold start, and you can see the error right in the console.

In my case, it was failing because my Lambda execution role had insufficient IAM privileges.

Comment: It seems that in contrast to running `$LATEST` the initialization for a version is invoked without the environment variables configured.

Comment: Bingo !, the lambda was erroring out. Ofcourse, it cannot be initialized by snapstart